# Xamarin forms app crash : Could not find method java.lang.Error.<init>, referenced from method android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable.<init>

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

[image]

I have an app, it had two page.First page login page it working properly.
 Second page is Download page.Download Page load time app crash and above picture showing crash message.
 showing Could not find method java.lang.Error., referenced from method android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable.

DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
 Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Please help me.

Comment: It seems to me the real error here is: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. You have some object that is `null` that you're trying to use.

Comment: i am debug with project , Download Page debug with properly and at last          in MainActivity  this.LoadApplication(new App());

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you, is this problem resolved?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks, it's solved, it's some Binding issue, i am solved it.Thanku for your reply.